# Android FAB icon always black with MaterialComponents theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, floating-action-button, androidx

I'm creating an Android app and I'm using the AndroidX libraries and Material design theme. My app theme on `styles.xml` is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I have the following FAB from a custom library:

```
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
        android:id="@+id/work_log_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/speeddial_scrolling_view_snackbar_behavior"
        app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:sdOverlayLayout="@id/overlay" />
```

And also tried the default FAB:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

No mater the color of the icon (a vector drawable), the icon inside the FAB (from the library and from the default) is always black. I have narrowed down the problem to the material design theme, since using the old `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` instead of the new `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` the icon inside the FAB gets the color of the original vector drawable.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the color of the icon defined as? Is it a theme attribute like `?attr/colorControlNormal` or a defined color like `#ffaacc` or `@color/orange` ?

Comment: The icon color is defined as `#FFF`

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71892873/12272687

Answer (score 173):

I solved this by using:

```
app:tint="@color/COLOR_OF_ICON"
```

and **NOT**:

```
android:tint="@color/COLOR_OF_ICON"
```

Reference: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md

Comment: What if the icon is multi coloured... Then tint is not the solution.

Comment: Totally was the fix for me!  I get so confused which of those attribute prefixes you are supposed to use.

Comment: @Shashanksingh use app:tint="@null" to use the icon's original color

Comment: Just a quick mention that, `app:tint` doesn't come up automatically. You have to type it.

Comment: None of these work for me. What's wrong with Google? Seriously. OMFg

Comment: Thank you so very much. You wouldn't believe how many days I wasted looking for this!

Answer (score 65):

For `MaterialComponents` Theme you can define the following colors.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/onPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/onSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/surface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/onSurface</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/error</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/onError</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/controlNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/controlActivated</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/controlHighlight</item>
        <item name="colorBackgroundFloating">@color/backgroundFloating</item>
    </style>
```

> `colorSecondary` is the responsible color for `FloatingActionButton`.
>   and
>   `colorOnSecondary` is the responsible color for icon color of `FloatingActionButton`.

In your `AppTheme` you have not defied the `colorSecondary`. So, it took the default black color from parent `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Reference : [Android dev summit, 2018 - The Components of Material Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPH3F0v1jB0&index=47&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8WFYCR9esqGGY0vOZm2l6e)

Comment: you can use app:tint="@color/colorAccent" to change it immediately.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman you can do that. The benefit of using the approach from Ifta is that you use theme instead. So then your styles and colors are flexible enough to apply in other theme.. such as dark theme :)

Comment: app:int did no work. What worked was ``<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/onSecondary</item>``

Comment: app:tint="@null" didin't work but this answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 48):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086747/8583692), if your icon has multiple colors or if you want to keep your icon original color(s), then assign `@null` as the tint:

```
app:tint="@null"
```

Answer (score 15):

According to the [GitHub documentation page for the Material Components library's FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md), the only attributes that affect the icon are

- `app:srcCompat`
- `app:tint`
- `app:maxImageSize`

In this case, since your color is defined as a constant (`#FFF`), the only one that seems to make sense is `app:tint`. Perhaps something in your theme has set this to black?

You ought to be able to override it by setting `app:tint="#FFF"` on your FAB.

Answer (score 7):

Is Your Icon is multicolor

Add Only

`app:tint="@null"`

but if you only want to change color

@dimen/fab_margin -> 16dp

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:tint="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Programmatically in  kotlin :

fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.your_drawable))

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just follow this

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/bottom_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_sign"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/app_dark_green"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/nav_view"
    app:tint="#FFF" />
```

And my result is

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use app:tint="@color/white"

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for it and the following code worked.

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/primarycolor"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:iconTint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vector asset as icon for FAB . Here is what worked for me .

app:tint is   changing vector icon color and  app:backgroundTint is changing background of FAB .

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/idFABAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Heinardi speed dial library. According to the document about [customizing items](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial#customizing-the-items), you can define a theme for the component:

```
<style name="Theme.FAB">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Note that `colorPrimary` defines the color of extended buttons,

`colorAccent` the color of main button,

`colorOnSecondary` the color of icon.

Then you can add the theme to `SpeedDialView`:

```
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
    android:id="@+id/speedDial"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_add_white"
    app:sdOverlayLayout="@id/speedDialOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
app:fabSize="mini"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_"
app:tint="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Color of icons are overrided by colorOnSecondary (see themes.xml).

To put the icon colour you want you must use:

```
app:tint="@colour/icon_colour"
```

And for the background:

```
app:backgroundTint="@colour/icon_colour"
```

You can change these colours automatically by the theme using https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043959/1200914

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add my 2 cents. There are a few options how to fix your color issue for Material Components. The majority of them are already covered in the answers.

However, there's another and, probably, more general approach in this case. You can set a default "floatingActionButtonStyle" to your theme which will be used for all FloatingActionButtons.

```
<style name="Theme.Design" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Theme.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Design.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="tint">@null</item>
</style>
```

More details about styling of FloatingActionButtons is available there [Theming Fabs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#theming-fabs)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar theme
To change the color of floating action button use the following

```
  <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/primary</item> // this will give the color to fab
  <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/white</item> // this sets the color of the icon on fab
```

To learn more about theming you can refer to Google Git Repository
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#container-attributes

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATED**

Shortly:
@gab-ledesma comment did the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843325/5451349

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
...
app:iconTint="@color/white"
app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white"
...
```

Finnaly `app:iconTint` changed an icon color.
I've found it in the source code:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L81

Of cource, you need to check the instruction before:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md