# Why is my FloatingActionButton icon black?

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx

Following is the code I'm using. I'm using androidx. Every FAB has a black icon, even if it has a white color.

mylayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/content_geral" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

style.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 207, accepted):

If you're using **AndroidX**, to change the color of the icon you must use `app:tint` opposed to `android:tint`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
/>
```

Comment: If "app:tint" does not work for you, "app:iconTint" worked for me for the ic_input_add button.

Answer (score 102):

I have an icon(vector) with multiple colors(attached file) but I cannot use **app:tint="@color/white"** because my icon's color turns to single color such as white and I did not need this.

So I Fixed my problem with set setting app:tint to null:

```
  app:tint="@null"
```

My Icon (SVG) :

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The `FloatingActionButton` class from AndroidX uses the `colorOnSecondary` theme attribute to tint its icon.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L39

If you follow the `MaterialComponents` theme definitions down into the base definitions, you'll see that the default value for `colorOnSecondary` is `design_default_color_on_secondary`... and *that* is defined as `#000000`.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/values/colors.xml#L26

You can fix this by either adding the `app:tint` attribute directly to your FloatingActionButton or by re-defining `@color/colorOnSecondary` in your theme to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 6):

You're changing **background** color of FAB, not the icon color.
To change **icon** color, use:

```
android:tint
```

**UPDATE**

You can also change color programmatically:

```
Drawable myFabSrc = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
Drawable willBeWhite = myFabSrc.getConstantState().newDrawable();
willBeWhite.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
myFabName.setImageDrawable(willBeWhite);
```

Comment: ...not work. =(

Comment: you can also try to change color programmatically with ColorFilter (updated my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `android:backgroundTint` this property sets the background color of FAB but to change the color of FAB icon use `android:tint` property like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
   />
```

Answer (score 2):

In your drawable folder click on

```
ic_cloud_upload
```

And change fillColor to

```
android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" // #FFFFFF is for white color
```

This will turn your black icon to white.