# issue with setting background drawable in FAB in material 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

So, I'm setting a custom background for my FAB.

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/landing_offer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_batch_gold"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
    app:maxImageSize="50dp" />
```

The given drawable is getting drawn on the FAB. But all it's color is gone. it's all black and looks ugly. How do I get the drawable with the color on my FAB. Thanks.

here is my vectordrawable

```
<vector android:height="42.859436dp" android:viewportHeight="42.94"
    android:viewportWidth="26.65" android:width="26.6dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#f0c419" android:pathData="M26.65,17A13.33,13.33 0,1 0,13.33 30.36,13.32 13.32,0 0,0 26.65,17"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#e64c3c" android:pathData="M13.33,3.7a13.21,13.21 0,0 1,8.14 2.8V0H5.18V6.5a13.26,13.26 0,0 1,8.15 -2.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#e64c3c" android:pathData="M13.33,30.36a13.26,13.26 0,0 1,-8.15 -2.8V42.94l8.15,-8.14 8.14,8.14V27.56a13.21,13.21 0,0 1,-8.14 2.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#ffe69f" android:pathData="M13.33,7.4l2.83,5.72l6.05,0.95l-4.29,4.45l1.33,5.91l-5.92,-2.57l-5.93,2.57l1.34,-5.91l-4.3,-4.45l6.05,-0.95l2.84,-5.72z"/>
</vector>
```

[image: here is the one that is shown in layout editor]

[image: when i use my fab in bottmappbar]

Comment: as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458821/why-is-my-floatingactionbutton-icon-black/54086747#54086747) if your background are colored then add `app:tint="@null"` will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some attributes.

Do it like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_batch_gold"
    app:tint="@color/colorFabTint"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar" />
```

Please note **app:tint** and **android:src** attr instead of app:srcCompat

Comment: I tried with those but there is still the same issue. I have a colorful vector drawable but it's coming in blue and black

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the result that you are getting? Post also your vector drawable.