# FAB backgroundTintList, doesn't work and sets border color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

If you use it in XML it works, but you can't set it programatically. I'm using this library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

For example:

```
filterHistoryFab.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context!!, R.color.pink)
```

XML:

```
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/filterHistoryFab"
            style="@style/FloatingActionButton"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_white" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/fab_margin</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
```

The background should be PINK, but it stays BLUE, with some pink in behind.
Link to how it looks: [LINK](http://prntscr.com/n3i8tw)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53365618/7666442

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that is for tint of the icon and not background.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. If you set in STYLE `backgroundTint` it will not work programatically. Maybe this is a bug. So the solution is to just remove this line:

```
 <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/dark_blue</item>
```

And it works perfectly.