# How to add PNG to floating action button in android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to display [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TMqGfWvnyixoc6XMj__I2ehv9jRLnNn1/view?usp=sharing) png as my floating action button. But when I set this as my src, I get a [black icon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idR46oHv_3jS7a9uyIzCvFHlNCB4eavB/view?usp=sharing) instead. How can I do it?

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:backgroundTint="@null"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_esaathi_icon"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:maxImageSize="56dp" />
```

**Edit:**
Sarath Siva's answer works fine.

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_02"
```

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843325/12020725

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

use it like this

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_02"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:maxImageSize="56dp"
        app:tint="@null"
        />
```

Comment: It works. How can I do the same, set background image, programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

remove background, try to set e.g. transparent or white color (or `@null`), but use custom lib attributes (e.g. `app:`) instead of built-in ones (`android:`)

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
app:tint="@android:color/transparent"
```