# Change app theme globally programatically

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, themes

I am writing an app which has both light and dark modes as declared here:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Noon" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="upper_bg">@drawable/day_sky_top</item>
    <item name="lower_bg">@drawable/day_sky</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="Night" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="upper_bg">@drawable/night_sky_top</item>
    <item name="lower_bg">@drawable/night_sky</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorNightDark</item>
</style>
```

By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004450/application-themes-change-and-imageview-src-based-on-app-theme-name), I created the following file:

**/res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="customAttrs">
        <attr name="upper_bg" format="reference" />
        <attr name="lower_bg" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And customized my ImageViews like this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:src="?attr/upper_bg"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:src="?attr/lower_bg"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

(Note that this is part of the code, all tags are properly closed.)

Everything works well provided I have:

```
boolean night = true;
setTheme(night ? R.style.Night : R.style.Noon);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // or whatever activity I'm in.
```

**on every single Activity of my app.** Is there a way to run this code ONCE so that my theme changes globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still add a `BaseActivity` to then override `override fun onCreate()`, delegating it the responsibility of `setTheme()` for any other `Activity` that inherits from it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val night = true
    setTheme(if (night) R.style.Night else R.style.Noon) 
}
```

if you don't prefer `BaseActivity`, you can create an extension function somewhere in charged of set theme according user preferences:

```
fun Activity.setTheme() {
    val night = true
    // Or even have more than two theme styles
    this.setTheme(if (night) R.style.Night else R.style.Noon)
}
```

To then be called like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme()
}
```

**UPDATE: Java code**

This class would be your base class for each required `Activity`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean night = true;
        setTheme(night ? R.style.Night : R.style.Noon);
    }
}
```

So now, imagine you have to implement "Feature 1" and "Feature 2", so that, you just inherits them from `BaseActivity`.

"Feature 1":

```
public class Feature1Activity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // <- BaseActivity's onCreate() will set theme for you
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_1);
    }
}
```

"Feature 2":

```
public class Feature2Activity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // <- BaseActivity's onCreate() will set theme for you
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea about Kotlin. Could you please translate it to Java?

Comment: @xvlaze, I already added a Java code update

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can !
You have to use method setDefaultNightMode() of class AppCompatDelegate that take the value of the theme you want to apply , the values available is MODE_NIGHT_NO & MODE_NIGHT_YES & MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM for light , night and phone default theme respectively , you can do something like this :

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(THE_MODE_YOU_WANT);
```

Its important to note that starting with AppCompat v1.0.0 , when this method get called it recreates all running activity to apply the theme .

If you are running Api 29 or higher , you should consider using Force Dark , you can check it all in the official [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) to get better understanding of it .

**Enjoy !**

Comment: But how about a custom style defined as R.style.mystyle?

Comment: You can just put in night mode theme file , then android will read it automatically when you change your theme to night mode .